# Require a JQuery drop down list example which loads data while scrolling down

Tags: jquery

I have a requirement to create a drop down list which will be empty while loading the page. When the user clicks on the drop down, I want to load the first 20 records (List of names or departments etc) from the SQL Server database using jQuery and json service. When the user scroll down to the last, we have to retain the first 20 records and load the next 20 records from the database.

Is any JQuery plugin control available for this. If anybody is aware of this control, please share the details. If this control is not available, then if anybody knows how to create the control using jquery with sample code, please help me to get this.

Comment: you can write your own using .`.scroll`.

Comment: Google Infinite scroll

Answer (score 1):

This is a good one, i've used it in many projects : http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

> Select2 is a jQuery based replacement for select boxes. It supports
>   searching, remote data sets, and infinite scrolling of results.